# Rails routes have no id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I added `resource :products, :path => 'catalog/'` to my `routes.rb`, but my routs look like this:

```
      products POST   /catalog(.:format)                            products#create
  new_products GET    /catalog/new(.:format)                        products#new
 edit_products GET    /catalog/edit(.:format)                       products#edit
               GET    /catalog(.:format)                            products#show
               PATCH  /catalog(.:format)                            products#update
               PUT    /catalog(.:format)                            products#update
               DELETE /catalog(.:format)                            products#destroy
```

Why do they have no `:id`s? For example, `product#show` should have URI `/products/:id(.:format)`, right?

Also,  `= link_to products_path(product), class: 'product' do` leads me to `http://localhost:3000/catalog.1`

Comment: Read about [*Singular Resources*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `resources :products` instead of `resource :proucts`. For more info: https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/rails-routes-difference-between-resource-and-resources-in-routes-rb/